# Angular app spanning subdomains

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

So I am building an angular app that allows people to create books and share them (digital books mind you) with a subdomain link.

So something like mycoolbook.theappsite.com would be a sharable link.

I (perhaps stupidly) built the routes so that editing books would be at the url "mycoolbook.theappsite.com/settings".

This being an angular page I am having to do hard redirects between those pages and so miss out on much of the SPA-y goodness. Is there a way to keep the app instance running between those pages?

If not I might move all the admin pages back behind the url like "theappsite.com/book/mycoolbook/settings" instead.

Is this at all possible?

I've already done all the hard work of getting sessions and ajax request working across the domains, it's just the state linking that becomes bothersome.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  You have a site under /settings, but what page are you trying to redirect to?  What error or what are you expecting vs what are you actually seeing?  I just don't understand your problem.

Comment: FOr instance navigating from book.domain.com to domain.com. Is there a way to do this without a page refresh?

Typically in an Angular app there is no page refresh, just some new stuff loaded in by ajax and the url in the address bar gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no and have the URL change to reflect it.  You cannot change book.domain.com -> domain.com because angular manipulates the URL, but only the fragment section of the URL in hash mode and just the path, search string, hash in HTML5 Mode.  Not the other parts of the URL.  If your application is using HTML5 mode your server must be able to map URLs properly so they return the correct page (ie index.html) as you change the URL.  That would mean both DNS locations would have to send back the same page.

Now you can send AJAX requests between the two domains provided you understand how to deal with cross domain issues (JSONP, CORS, etc).

Comment: Ya this is exactly what I figured out by experiment. I got the CORs stuff setup just before deciding to change the url structure to avoid using subdomains for normal app pages. :D Oh well now I understand CORs.

I ended up having the subdomain routes go into a seperate angular app build from a subset of the modules making up the main app. This is a 'shared' pages and having a smaller payload is better on mobile anyways.